# Create music with 396Hz solfeggio

Tags: logic-pro

I create guided meditations with own music. I would like to create (or convert) my Logic Pro projects to use 396 Hz for A4?

How should I do this?

Comment: It's not 'magic' btw, it's a load of unfounded twaddle [to be uncharacteristically polite], mainly these days touted by 'youtewb mystics' in an effort to sound 'mysterious'. It more underlines how little they understand of music & music history. You could save yourself the effort & not bother, or you could just transpose everything a tone down & see if anyone can tell it's in D rather than E…

Comment: @Tetsujin It can all be classified as "quantum mysticism". Which is using sudo-science to sell spiritual BS. It started with real scientists pushing the mysticism of quantum mechanics while leaving out the true explanations of what's actually going on. My sister is drawn in by this stuff. You can imagine how frustrating it is for me!

Comment: @n00dles - its right up there with the flat earthers.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have a score you want to play with A4=396Hz tune fork.

The following page tells you how to adjust the tone of a pre-rendered file (typically WAV) https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207960

2 semitones down makes your tune from 440Hz to 392Hz. Then 17.6 cents up makes your tune from 392 to 396Hz.

If it is possible to enter high values as cents, you would better proceed in one step : -182.4 cents will change the tune from 440 to 396Hz.

(There are also online conversion tools like https://www.432hzconverter.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Logic Pro can adjust the global project tuning that software instruments use in the Project Settings, as explained in the manual: https://support.apple.com/guide/logicpro/tuning-project-settings-lgcp452f2693/mac

Or, as Frédéric says, you can alter the overall playback rate of existing audio recordings.

All that said, though, Tetsujin is correct that folks online who promote alternate frequencies for concert A as some sort of “superior frequency” or “healing tones” do so out of complete ignorance (or willful misunderstanding) of how music and sound actually work, and transposing your projects in this way won’t magically make perfect mathematical ratios or anything like that. Equal temperament gets in the way of any kind of elegant numerical relationships, and music played with the purported “sacred geometry numbers” or whatever will simply sound *bad* to the majority of listeners. Adam Neely and Ben Jordan have some insightful explorations into how these tonal relationships actually play out in practice, for those wanting further research.